# How to avoid change in matplotlib background image aspect ratio and instead crop it into right size?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have a matplotlib background image that keeps the original aspect ratio even when you zoom and stretch the plot. Aka: the image would crop out the parts that aren't on the screen and zomm the image when you zoom the plot so that it would keep the original aspect of the image and doesn't make it stretched all while keeping so much of it as possible on the screen. so far I have not gotten it to work as it either changes the axis of the plot or stretches the image.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
...
plt.locator_params(axis='y', nbins=max(y) + 1)
img = plt.imread("plot_background.png")
ax.imshow(img, extent=[-1, 20, 0, 10 + 1],aspect="auto")

...
plt.show()
```